# What is the event that will fire after assigning customer to group in Magento?

Tags: magento, events, magento-1.9

I have to fire an observer method when the admin assign customer(s) to group on `adminhtml`. Can you help me which event is it?

I tried `adminhtml_customer_save_after` but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any one event below

customer_save_before,
customer_save_after

```
<global>
    <events>
        <customer_save_after>
            <observers>
                <change_customer_group>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>modulename/observer</class>
                    <method>ChangeCustomerGroup</method>
                </change_customer_group>
            </observers>
        </customer_save_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

Comment: Thank you, I did it with `customer_save_after`